# What is the best way to iterate multidimensional array in node.js/javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multidimensional-array

I am trying to iterate multidimensional array in Node.js. I have array in JSON object like this :

```
{
    "operationalHours": [
        [
            {
                "opens": "11: 15AM",
                "closes": "11: 30AM"
            },
            {
                "opens": "11: 30AM",
                "closes": "11: 45AM"
            },
            {
                "opens": "11: 45AM",
                "closes": "12: 00PM"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "opens": "12: 15AM",
                "closes": "12: 30AM"
            },
            {
                "opens": "12: 30AM",
                "closes": "12: 45AM"
            },
            {
                "opens": "01: 00AM",
                "closes": "01: 15AM"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know the best way to iterate this in node.js?

Comment: checkout underscore http://underscorejs.org/ or dotslash they are both javascript libraries that make iterating over almost anything much easier

Comment: if you describe how exactly you want to query this JSON object then we can help you more

Comment: Yes, please provide some context, I don't think you just want to `console.log` the content of the array.

Comment: Why don't you share some more inputs about the issue ?

Comment: Thanks folks lodash solved my problem for both iterating and querying as helped by Arthur.

Answer (score 0):

The most "quicker" way to iterate an array in javascript is:

```
var i; 
for (i = myarray.length; i--;) {
  console.log(myarray[i]);
}
```

Iteration counter in a reverse order - from the biggest number to zero, usually increases the speed, because operation of comparison with 0 is a little more effective, than operation of comparison with array length or with any other number, different to 0.

To iterate object inside of each array element you can use `for in`  cycle:

```
var i, j; 
for (i = myarray.length; i--;) {
  for (j in myarray[i]) {
      console.log(j, myarray[i][j]);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash):

```
_.forEach(operationalHours, function(el, key) {

});
```

You can also find element:

```
var items = _.findWhere(operationalHours[0], {"opens": "11: 30AM"})
```

Comment: Yes lodash helped me to iterate and query the array. Thanks